# How to select element X just if it is enclosed in tag Y?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to select `<a>` **if** it was enclosed in the `<li>` tag. Something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <a>select this</a>
   </li>
</ul>
      <a>Don't select this</a>
```

How can I do that?

Comment: `$('li > a')`  - selects only `a` which is **direct** child of `li`. `$('li a')` - selects `a` which is child of `li`

Comment: @Andrey Thanks, If you wrote an answer for my question, It must be marked as my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using jquery it can be done like this - `$("li a")`

Comment: what if the case is like this? `<ul>
   <li>
      <ul>
   <li>
      <a>select this</a>
   </li>
</ul>
      <a>Don't select this</a>
   </li>
</ul>` http://jsfiddle.net/0sj6wrc7/

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy what makes you think it could be the case? And btw what let you think it shouldnt be selected?

Comment: @A.Wolff My instinct!

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy ok but i think your instinct is wrong, rereading question, second anchor should be matched anyway:  ~I want to select <a> if it was enclosed in the <li> tag

Answer (score 1):

**The best way would be assigning a class or id to that  and then select it by class or id.**

If you don't want to do it (feels really wrong unless you want all tags < a > inside an < li >) what you can do is

```
$("li a") - using jQuery - will return all <a> inside a <li>
```

Or using pure javascript

```
var lis = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
```

select the li you want (example lis[0]) and then

```
lis[0].getElementsByTagName("a")
```

Or you can iterate through all lis and select all < a > inside of them if that's what you want

Answer (score 0):

You can just select element from jquery request like from array.

```
$("li a")[0]
```

or if you don't want to leave jquery use:

```
$("li a").get(0)
```

Comment: This answer is not the answer of my question, I wanted to define a condition to selects all `<a>` children in the `<li>` tag. your solution always selects first `<a>` in the `<li>`